# Define various Trim size through a .sty file

Tags: crop

I'm trying to write a package, which can supports various Trim sizes through option in `TeX` application file, and my tags are follows:

**Definition in my `.sty` file**

```
\newif\ifsixbynine  
\newif\ifsevenbynine
\newif\ifeightbynine

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\usepackage[a4,center,cam,info]{crop}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ifsixbynine
\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{6truein}%
\fi

\ifsevenbynine
\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{7truein}%
\fi

\ifeightbynine
\setlength{\paperheight}{9truein}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8truein}%
\fi


\addtolength\topmargin{-1in}

\setlength\textwidth{26pc}

\setlength\textheight{39pc}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{5pc}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}    % subtract out the 1 inch driver margin
\setlength\@tempdima{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-\textwidth}
\addtolength\@tempdima{-5pc}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\@tempdima}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1in}

\DeclareOption{6x9}{\global\sixbyninetrue}
\DeclareOption{7x9}{\global\sevenbyninetrue}
\DeclareOption{8x9}{\global\eightbyninetrue}

\ProcessOptions

\endinput
```

**Content of my `.tex` file**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[6x9]{test}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

But the output doesn't come what I expected. Can you help me what I did wrong in my definitions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring your options and calling the `\ProcessOptions` macro at the end of the package file. Depending on the provided options, this macro sets the appropriate flags (`\sixbynine` and others), so it needs to be called *before* the flags are used.

Comment: Thanks a lot...you saved me....